# Cocos2dx - How do i predict the movement of object if setVelocity returns different results?

Tags: synchronization, cocos2d-x, physics

I want to make synchronization movement between client and client.
I've read some posts about simulate physics on the server and predict the movement on the client.

However, how do i do it even if i have the formula if `setVelocity` on Physics engine returns different results randomly (https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/130858/get-different-result-on-different-devices-same-resolution-after-setvelocity)?

Basically, using `setVelocity` is kind of making prediction movement on the client before getting result from server.

But i never can have good prediction if physics engine return inconsistent results. Only way is to sync coordinate frame by frame?